# Translate a Field's Label in a Drupal Content Type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, internationalization, cck

I'm trying out i18n with my Drupal 6 content types and the field values get translated ok, but not the field labels.

Is there a way to translate this?

Comment: Did you try the translation interface yet?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to reopen this thread, if anyone lands here looking for a way to translate field labels for **Drupal 7**, read below.

In Drupal 7, the core function `template_preprocess_field()` was introduced. Using it within our template.php file, we can pass each field label through a `t()` function.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$vars, $hook) {

  // Check to make sure there's a label and it's visible.
  if(isset($vars['label']) && $vars['label_hidden'] === FALSE)
  {
     $vars['label'] = t($vars['label']);
  }

}
```

Comment: Better solution for Drupal 7: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/154234/101329

Answer (score 1):

try this
http://drupal.org/node/474122/release